# Extracting one column based on max of other columns of a Dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

I am trying to fetch the value in column in 'a' corresponding to the max values od columns 'c','d' and 'e' and then store it in a vector.
I have written below code which gives column 'a' data along with two NA.
Can somebody help me to fetch the exact data using sapply.

```
a<-c('A','B','C','D','E')
b<-c(10,30,45,25,40)
c<-c(19,23,25,37,39)
d<-c(43,21,17,14,26)
e<-c(NA,23,45,32,NA)
df<-data.frame(a,b,c,d,e)

A1<-vector("character",3)
for (i in 3:5){
  A1[i]<-c(df[which(df[,i]==max(df[,i],na.rm = TRUE)),1])
  A1    
}
```

Actual Result: > A1
[1] ""  ""  "E" "A" "C"

Expected Result: A1 should have "E" "A" "C"

Please suggest a solution using sapply.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can use `mapply`

```
unname(mapply(function(x, y) x[which(y == max(y, na.rm = TRUE))], df[1], df[3:5]))
#[1] "E" "A" "C"
```

---

In the loop, the indexing starts from 3:5 which is the index for the columns while the 'A1' vector object is initialized to 3 elements. If the assignment starts from the 3rd element onwards, the `vector` just appends new elements while keeping the first 2 elements untouched.

```
A1<-vector("character",3)
A1
#[1] "" "" ""

A2 <- A1
A2[3:5] <- 15
A2
#[1] ""   ""   "15" "15" "15"  #### this is the same thing happening in the loop
```

Instead, we can loop over the sequence and then assign

```
i1 <- 3:5
for(i in seq_along(i1)) {
   A1[i] <- df[which(df[,i1[i]]==max(df[,i1[i]],na.rm = TRUE)),1]
}

A1
#[1] "E" "A" "C"
```

Comment: Thanks for the for loop modification.
Also, I got the command with sapply too.
sapply(3:5, function(x,y) y[which(y[,x]==max(y[,x],na.rm = TRUE)),1],y=df)

It gives the result just suggest me in case any mistake in the command.